# Getting a users mailbox current history Id

Tags: gmail-api

I'd like to start syncing a users mailbox going forward so I need the most recent historyId of the users mailbox. There doesn't seem to be a way to get this with one API call.

The gmail.users.history.list endpoint contains a historyId which seems to be what I need, from the docs:

```
historyId   unsigned long   The ID of the mailbox's current history record.
```

However to get a valid response from this endpoint you must provide a `startHistoryId` as a parameter.

The only alternative I see is to make a request to list the users messages, get the most recent history id from that, then make a request to gmail.users.history.list providing that historyid to get the most recent one.

Other ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Did you check out https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync ?

Depending on what your use-case is, to avoid races between your current state and when you start to forward sync, you'll need to provide an appropriate historyId.  If there were a "get current history ID" then anything between your previous state and when you got those results would be lost.  If you don't have any particular existing state (e.g. only want to get updates and don't care about anything before that) then you can use any historyId returned (e.g. on a message or thread) as you mention.

Comment: Yup saw those docs and I am exactly talking about the case where I don't have any existing state and only want updates in the future.

Comment: If I use gmail.users.messages.list I'd need to make two calls correct? 1 to get a list of messages, then another call to get the history Id of the most recent message (i.e. the first message in the response of the first call)

Comment: actually this is worse than I thought. We actually need to do 3 calls to make this work. One to get the list of messages. The another call to get the contents of the single message to get that history id. Then a call to get the history starting from that history id which then responds with the current history id.

Comment: There is now a gmail.users.getprofile() method that returns the current historyId of a mailbox.  Docs not yet pushed but it should be available in client libraries or API explorer:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.getProfile

Hope that helps!

Comment: @EricDeFriez hi!, i tried that link it works fine on developer.google.com but i tried it with Java client API it only returns **userId**  which i pass it when calling **Gmail.Users.GetProfile(java.lang.String userId)**.

Answer (score 2):

Small example for `C#` users (mentioned in comments by `@EricDeFriez`).

Nuget package `Google.Apis.Gmail.v1` must be installed. See  also [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) for .NET developers.

```
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

var req = service.Users.GetProfile("me");
req.Fields = "historyId";
var res = req.Execute();

Console.WriteLine("HistoryId: " + res.HistoryId);
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer is related to the Java Gmail API Client Library using a service account. 
I found that the `gmail.users.getprofile()` will not work as the object that it returns is of type `Class Gmail.Users.GetProfile` which does not have an interface to getting a historyId.

`com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Profile` actually has a `getHistoryId()` function, but calling `service.users().getProfile()` will return a `Class Gmail.Users.GetProfile`object instead.

To get around this, I use the history.list() function which will always return the latest historyId as part of its response.

```
    Gmail service = createGmailService(userId); //Authenticate
    BigInteger startHistoryId = BigInteger.valueOf(historyId);
    ListHistoryResponse response = service.users().history().list("me")                
    .setStartHistoryId(startHistoryId).setMaxResults(Long.valueOf(1)).execute();
```

I set the max number of results to be 1 to limit the unnecessary data that I get returned back and I will receive a payload that looks like:

> {"history":[{"id":"XXX","messages":[{"id":"XXX","threadId":"XXX"}]}],"historyId":"123456","nextPageToken":"XXX"}

The historyId (123456) will be the current historyId of the user. You can grab that historyId using `response.getHistoryId()`

You can also see that the latest historyId is given in the response if you use the API tester for Users.history: list

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list